# How to call a element by partialinktext using its parent class in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML code is as follows

```
<div class="a-row">
<a class="a-link-normal" title="1.0 out of 5 stars" href="/gp/customer-reviews/RBDVABUKMPJY8/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B071NZZHF9">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-star a-star-1 review-rating" data-hook="review-star-rating">
<span class="a-icon-alt">1.0 out of 5 stars</span>
</i>
</a>
<span class="a-letter-space"/>
<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/RBDVABUKMPJY8/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B071NZZHF9">One Star</a>
</div>
```

I want to call 1.0 out of 5 stars in the span class using the parent class='a-row'.

Can someone help on how can we call as it has to be called using partiallinktext method using only partiallinktext= out of 5 stars.

Comment: I think you need to iterate through all elements with `class='a-row'` and find the `partiallinktext`.

Comment: If anybody find the question valid! Please do up-vote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

First look for the `Span` elem like:

```
WebElement spanElem = driver.findElement(By.className("a-row")).findElement(By.tagName("span"));
```

Then use below:

```
spanElem.findElement(By.partialLinkText("out of 5 stars"));
```

Another Solution:

```
List<WebElement> allParents = driver.findElements(By.className("a-row"));
for (WebElement elem : allParents) {
    WebElement spanElem = elem.findElement(By.tagName("span"));
    //System.out.println(spanElem.getText());

    spanElem.findElement(By.partialLinkText("out of 5 stars"));
    //System.out.println(spanElem.findElement(By.partialLinkText("out of 5 stars")).getText());         
}
```

OR

```
 List<WebElement> rstar = dr.findElements(By.className("a-row")); 
 for(WebElement erstar : rstar) 
 { 
     erstar.findElement(By.partialLinkText("out of 5 stars"));
     String c = erstar.getText(); 
     System.out.println(c);      
 }
```

Hopefully it resolves your issues.

Comment: I cannot use it directly! as same partiallinktext is present for other element under some other Parent class.
So i wanted to point the parent class and then call the element by partiallinktext.

Comment: Just wait. I am coming with another solution.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava Hey brother! I updated the answer. Please try this and let me know your feedback

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava I updated the answer with searching tagName. please try and let me know.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava why do you need partialLinkText? You can just use `spanElem` to find your exact link. In my solution, the first line of code is enough to get exact link element.

Comment: Then use the `spanElem.getText()` to get the link text.

Comment: This does not help me as your spanElem for me is a List of webelements that is being stored and are printed one by one. So is there any other way.
My code goes as follows:
List<WebElement> rstar = dr.findElements(By.className("a-row"));
      rstar.findElement(By.partialLinkText("out of 5 stars"));
      for(WebElement erstar : rstar) {
       String c = erstar.getText();
        System.out.println(c);

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava you can use like below:

List<WebElement> rstar = dr.findElements(By.className("a-row")); 
for(WebElement erstar : rstar) 
 { 
 erstar.findElement(By.partialLinkText("out of 5 stars"));
String c = erstar.getText(); 
System.out.println(c);   
}

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava I updated your given code. hopefully it will work.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava hey bro! did it work for you that I updated the answer last.

Comment: Thanks for the help dude @AliAzam. I have posted an answer that worked for me. It worked when i went for getAttribute using innertext.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava if you really got a little bit help from my answer, then why aren't you voting up my answer so that others can help from it. I had given a lot of effort to it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way through which i got the output is as follows:

```
List<WebElement> rstar = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='cm_cr-review_list']//div[@class='a-row']//a[@class='a-link-normal']//i"));
                String c;
                    for(WebElement erstar : rstar) {
                        c=erstar.getAttribute("innerText");

                        System.out.println(c);
```

Thanks for the help @AliAzam :)

Comment: If  my answer is really help, then you should accept and vote up that answer.

Comment: No bro! it didnt worked in my case! Hope it can help someone else!